# Ubuntu 14.04, setup server IP for datacenter, IPMI

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ipmi

i'm going to build a server and send it to a datacenter. I got this from the datacenter. They told me to setup the server with it.

VLAN: 256

IPv4: 79.133.49.168/29

IPv6: 2a01:07e0:0000:0256::/64

Address:   79.133.49.168

Netmask:   255.255.255.248 = 29

Wildcard:  0.0.0.7

Network:   79.133.49.168/29

HostMin:   79.133.49.169

HostMax:   79.133.49.174

Broadcast: 79.133.49.175 

Hosts/Net: 6

What am i supposed to do with this? I guess i'm supposed to edit my "/etc/network/interfaces". But what's the gateway? Address, netmask, network ...ok. But where's the gateway?

Do i need something special for the IPMI (Supermicro X10SLL-F Mainboard)?

Would be bad if they plug the server in and i can't access it because of the config.

Regards

Comment: Ask the DC? They do know vest about their systems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable question to ask the technical support. And yes, you do need a separate address for the IPMI. This whole block of information. does, in fact, look ridiculous. Some kind of the ipcalc output.

Answer (score 0):

They are giving you a block of ip's. You can pick any one of the 5 in the block. You need to ask them the ip of the router. More than likely it's going to be 169. So, example for the interfaces file:

address 79.133.49.170

netmask 255.255.255.248

gateway 79.133.49.169

Again, you need to verify with them that their router is 79.133.49.169.

Use 1 for the server, and one for the IPMI.